# Select objects with certain prefix in maya with Python

Tags: maya

I would like to select al objects with a certain prefix.

screenshot of outliner:

[image]

the only way I found is to select all lights , but I want only the lights with this prefix to append in my array.

What I have now : 
selectionLights = cmds.ls(type=['aiAreaLight'])
lights.extend(selectionLights)

If someone can help me , would be amazing !

Comment: I know in mel this is possible , but I want to do it only with python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the python commands work mostly like the mel commands it should work like this:

```
cmds.ls("PainterLight*")
```